# How to create a list from button items and populate them by a list?

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I have two DropDownButtons (ToolStripDropDownItem) - btn01 and btn02

I would like btn02 to be a sorted list of the items of btn01.

I've currently got.

```
List<string> list = new List(btn01.DropDownItems); //  I want to create a list
list.Sort();
btn02.DropDownItems = list; // sorted list should be btn02 items.
```

First and third line have syntax errors.

Comment: Hmmm... Could you point us to the source of `DropDownButton`? Otherwise we cannot help you since we do not know what `DropDownButton.DropDownItems` is...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by DropDownButton, can you explain more about it please. Also I think one error you are getting on the first line in you need to add the data type of the list you want so `new List<string>(...)`

Comment: these are ToolStripDropDownButtons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work.

It's not the prettiest code, and can be reduced down a number of lines, but I wanted to make sure it was clear.

```
var unorderedList = new List<ToolStripItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems.Count;i++ )
{
    unorderedList.Add(toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems[i]);
}

var orderedList = unorderedList.OrderBy(l => l.Text).ToList();
toolStripDropDownButton2.DropDownItems.AddRange(orderedList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error on the first row is because the DropDownItems isn't a collection of strings, Try this :

```
var list = DropDownItems.ToList();
```

If you want them as strings you can do like this:

```
var list = new List<string>();
foreach(var item in DropDownItems)
{
list.Add(item.ToString());
}
```

What is DropDownItems? Could you add some more information about this control?

Comment: these are ToolStripDropDownButtons

Comment: ok, these contains ToolStripDropDownItem, but i'cant figure out how to enumerate them, sort, then put em back, sorry.. i made a small test solution with this control but can't find the solution for you.

Comment: @ Jonas, ThankYou. I suppose solution is something with array, and then Add each element to btn02. We'll see.

Comment: No problem, to bad i couldn't find the solution for you. Hope you find someone that can help you with this issue.

Comment: You have to be sure that the items in `DropDownItems` are all string at first, because the item could be `Image` too.

Comment: @KirinYao, Thanks, items are string, placed by reading xml nodes